# Como criar um webhook no Gitlab para atualizar um repositório espelho no Github?

Tags: github

Eu gostaria de criar um webhook no Gitlab para atualizar um repositório espelho no Github sempre que houver um `push`. Eu consultei esta [página de demonstração](http://demo.gitlab.com/help/web_hooks), mas não entendi muito bem como fazer.

Minha versão do Gitlab é a 6.5. Aqui está a página de configuração:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em URL, devo colocar o repositório GitHub que gostaria de atualizar? Ou seria o arquivo JSON com as modificações geradas pelo push? Está bem difícil encontrar uma documentação sobre como fazer.

Comment: Por que os downvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Entendendo *Web Hooks*

***Web Hook*** é um método de receber notificações de eventos ocorridos em aplicações web. Quando algo acontece numa aplicação que suporta Web Hooks, ela faz uma requisição para a URL configurada enviando detalhes do que ocorreu.

Essa técnica permite realizar integrações da aplicação com outras ou até estender as funcionalidades da mesma de forma totalmente desacoplada, sem que seja necessário modificar a aplicação, injetar algum tipo de código ou script, etc.

Portanto, isso não vai enviar o repositório diretamente para o GitHub ou qualquer outro site. Cabe a você deve construir uma aplicação que escute aos eventos e tome a ação desejada, no caso, clonar o repositório.

## Verificando qual evento usar

A [documentação atual](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/web_hooks/web_hooks.html) mostra quais são os eventos gerados e que conteúdo a URL configurada receberá.

Por exemplo, o primeiro caso é quando alguém atualiza o repositório fazendo um `push`. A URL configurada vai receber uma requisição HTTP com o cabeçalho (*header*) `X-Gitlab-Event` com valor `Push Hook`. O corpo da requisição conterá detalhes sobre as alterações, como o usuário que fez o `push` e quais *commits* foram enviados.

## Implementando sua aplicação

Ao final da documentação há um exemplo de como implementar uma aplicação que escuta aos eventos. Você deve fazer algo parecido.

Pode ser em qualquer linguagem com qualquer framework, mas você será responsável pelo sistema que escuta os eventos na URL especificada.

Ao receber uma requisição originada por um evento `push`, sua aplicação deve então clonar o repositório de origem (GitLab) e  fazer o `push` no de destino (GitHub).